# Javascript anomaly while preventing button double submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms, button, post

I have a form submit button that starts disabled and is enabled when conditions are met (the form completed).  To prevent double submissions, I am using a simple "onclick disable button".  It disables the button as expected, but the form does not post the action.  Nothing happens at all.  Can anyone see my error or correct the form to make it properly submit?

```
    <form method="post" action="log.php" >
    ...
    <INPUT TYPE="submit" name="submit" VALUE="LOG"  onClick="this.disabled=true" title="Log the Comment" disabled>
```

Comment: The code you put in the event handler fires before the browser built in code for the object. So, you're setting the button to disabled prior to the browser submitting the form. You could work around this by using a regular button and conditionally submitting the form manually in the event handler.

Comment: Do that `onSubmit` rather than `onClick`

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply! You are all correctly identifying the problem; however, none the proposed solutions do not seem to work. The submit php takes time making the user double click. I can't seem to stop the submit from happening twice.

Comment: Added an alternative answer, @user3283304. It's a little more involved that a simple custom event handler but it's also a little more elegant imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my suggestion in the comment to your question, you could use an overlay div. It's a fixed position div that is positioned over the entire page with a `z-index` of `999` (to put it on top of everything). When its `display` css attribute is set to `none`, it is not displayed / rendered on the page, but when it's empty, it is drawn and covers everything preventing user interaction with the elements in the page. The `onclick` handler for the `Submit` button unhides this div prior to submitting the form. The div has a 30% opacity so you can see there is something covering the page but can still see the other elements in the page.

I put together a php script that generates some junk data in a server side text file containing an integer and iterates it every load and so you can see when updates are occurring on the server side. This proves for you that the overlay prevents duplicate submissions.

```
<?php  
    // THIS JUST RECORDS SOME JUNK DATA AND INCREMENTS IT EACH LOAD
    // IN A TEXT FILE TO SHOW THAT THE DATA IS NOT UPDATED MORE 
    // THAN ONCE PER CLICK 
    if (isset($_GET['i'])) {
        file_put_contents("./record.txt", intval(file_get_contents("./record.txt"), 10) + 1);
    } else {
        file_put_contents("./record.txt", "1");
    }
    // THIS SIMULATES EXTENSIVE SERVER SIDE PROCESSING ... FIVE SECONDS WORTH
    sleep(5);
?>

<!--THIS IS THE OVERLAY DIV THAT BLOCKS PAGE INTERACTION DURRING SERVR SIDE PROCESSING
    THE OVERLAY IS FIXED (SO ITS POSITION IS RELATIVE TO THE BROWSER WINDOW RATHER THAN
    THE DOCUMENT) AND HAS LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, AND BOTTOM POSITIONS THAT MAKE IT FIT 
    OVER THE ENTIRE BROWSER WINDOW.
    THE BACKGROUND COLOR IS A LIGHT GRAY AND HAS AN OPACITY OF 30%
    THESE CAN BE ADJUSTED, MAYBE YOU COULD PUT A "LOADING" GIF OR SOMETHING IN IT
    AND MAKE IT FIT JUST OVER THE FORM RATHER THAN THE ENTIRE WINDOW...
    I PUT THE CSS IN THE "STYLE" ATTRIBUTE RATHER THAN IN A STYLE NODE / CSS SCRIPT
    YOU SHOULD PUT IT IN A CSS SCRIPT
-->
<div 
 id="formoverlay" 
 style="position:fixed; 
        left:0; 
        top:0; 
        right:0; 
        bottom:0; 
        background-color:#aaa; 
        filter:alpha(opacity=30); 
        opacity:.3; 
        z-index:999; 
        display:none;"
></div>

<!--THIS IS A FORM THAT SUBMITS TO A PHP PAGE CALLED ONCLICKSUBMIT.PHP (THIS PAGE)-->
<form method="GET" action="onclicksubmit.php">
    <!--HIDDEN INPUT ELEMENT NAMED i. PHP WRITES THE VALUE FROM THE "DATA FILE" ABOVE
        IN ITS "VALUE" ATTRIBUTE
    -->
    <input name="i" id="i" type="hidden" value="<?php echo file_get_contents("./record.txt");?>" />
    <!--THE ONCLICK EVENT OF THIS SUBMIT UNHIDES THE "FORMOVERLAY" DIV THAT COVERS THE PAGE-->
    <input type="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('formoverlay').style.display='';"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is a very simple but creative solution! I'll try to plug it into my code soon.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm thinking is the onClick function gets ran ON CLICK so it never submits. Did you attempt putting the submit and disable on your JavaScript page and having it run everything from there?

```
function sub()
{
     document.getElementById("form name").submit();
     this.disabled=true;
}
```

then in onClick put "sub()". You could also get rid of the type="submit" in HTML.

this way, the code will run the submit function and then disable the button after. You can also put the redirect in the function as well as:

```
window.location.replace("...");
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposal!  Your code submits, but I can still double click and force a double submission.  Is that just something I have to live with?

Comment: Have you tried adding an if statement for the double click? document.getElementById('...').addEventListener('dblclick', function(){
  do nothing
}, false);